# WPF Xaml Image from Converter

Tags: wpf, image, xaml, data-binding, uri

i cant bind an image to source from converter?

```
<!-- Works fine -->
<Image Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="4" Grid.RowSpan="6" Margin="5">     
      <Image.Source>
          C:\pictures\Becker.png
      </Image.Source>
</Image>


<!-- Works not -->
<Image Source="{Binding ClientPicture, Converter={StaticResource clientpictureconv}, ConverterParameter={Binding ClientNumber}}"/>
```

In the converter i give back the hardcoded picture Uri (from the top). If i replace the Image with Textblock, the full uri is shown. But the picture in Image not.

What can i do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because Image.Source does not take a `URI` object; it takes an `ImageSource` object. Your converter should create one of those and pass it back. Put this in your converter, and it'll work:

```
return new BitmapImage(myUri);
```

Note that `BitmapImage` is a type of `ImageSource`.

Your first example works because XAML implicitly converts the URI string to an ImageSource for you. It can't do that when you explicitly pass back a URI object using your converter.

Comment: Also as far as I remember you can't bind converterparameter - you might be able to do something about the binding you get, but it is easier to use a multibinding with converter.